# How to control the slider speed for AWE theme for WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, slider, wordpress-theming, themes

I'm using this [AWE theme](https://www.codexcoder.com/products/awe-free-one-page-wordpress-theme/) and can't find the place to reduce the transition speed for each slide. I wish to make it slower so that people can read the slide.

Answer (score 0):

You can find decrease the transition speed in the style of class "item" it should be written as inner-carousel > .item